# kafka-consumer-groups.sh equivalent?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using 0.10.2 version. I would like to know does any Kafka java API can  fetch the offset info like using:

```
./bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server 192.168.0.28:9092 --describe --group test
```

Since I want to show all this offset information in my application without using the CLI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's an equivalent in the Java client; I just looked at that script and it calls a scala class `ConsumerGroupCommand`.

I am not familiar with scala, but it looks like that class doesn't expose the internal classes (e,g, `ZkConsumerGroupService`) that implement the command so it doesn't look like it can be invoked from a user app.

Looks like it writes directly to stdout anyway, rather than producing an object with the results.

I suppose you could run it and capture stdout...

```
ConsumerGroupCommand.main(new String[] {"--bootstrap-server", "localhost:9092", 
            "--describe",
            "--group", "test"});
```

Or, you'd have to lift a bunch of code from that class.